# Combine Series of Columns in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have a dataframe where I need to combine every tenth column. As an example my dataframe looks like this:

```
V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
A     B     C     D     E     F
```

What I'd like is:

```
first second third
AD    BE     CF
```

to do this I've been trying to use lapply and a custom function:

```
col_unite <- c(c('V1', 'V4', 'first'), c('V2', 'V5', 'second'), c('V3', 'V6', 'third'))
#function that combines columns and gives a new name
unite_cols <- function(dataframe, col_list){
  dataframe[[col_list[3]]] <- paste0(dataframe[[col_list[1]]], ', ', 
  dataframe[[col_list[2]]])
  dataframe
}

new_df <- lapply(col_unite, function(x){
   df <- unite_cols(orig_df, x)
   # df[x[3]] <- paste0(test[x[1]], ', ', test[x[2]]) # a different attempt
   return(df)
})
```

I know I could do this with a bunch of unite statements, or maybe there is a way to do this with a loop and unite. But given the number of columns I need to loop through I'd like to try to do it in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I define the data frame.

```
df <- read.table(text = "V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
A     B     C     D     E     F", header = TRUE, colClasses = "character")
```

Then, I use `lapply` to go through and `paste` each column with the column 3 places over and then recast the resulting list as a data frame.

```
lapply(1:(ncol(df)/2), function(x)paste0(df[,c(x,x+3)], collapse = "")) %>% 
  data.frame
```

The pipe (`%>%`) requires the `dplyr` package.

```
#    X.AD. X.BE. X.CF.
# 1    AD    BE    CF
```

---

### Edit

Alternatively, I create a list of paired column names to combine. Much the same approach otherwise.

```
MyList <- list(c("V1", "V4"), c("V2", "V5"), c("V3", "V6"))

lapply(MyList, function(x)paste0(df[,x], collapse = "")) %>% 
    data.frame

#    X.AD. X.BE. X.CF.
# 1    AD    BE    CF
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems promising. Can you think of a way to use a list of columns like `c(c('V1', 'V4'), c('V2', 'V5'))` to combine instead of using `1:(ncol(df)/2)`

Comment: Yes, wow, as soon as I saw your edit I realized I just needed my vector to be a list for lapply to properly loop and then a few edits to the function if I use that original method

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this

```
n <- 4
rbind.data.frame(apply(matrix(df, nrow = n - 1), 1, paste0, collapse = ""))
#   X.AD. X.BE. X.CF.
#1    AD    BE    CF
```

Here we combine every `n = 4`th entry by casting the `data.frame` as a `matrix` with `n - 1` rows, `paste0`ing rows, and converting the resulting `matrix` back into a `data.frame`.

The only thing left is to come up with suitable column names.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
A     B     C     D     E     F", header = T, colClasses = "character")
```

Comment: That did end up working, thanks! The only unfortunate part is realizing that my columns are not actually evenly spaced for every three. I'm going to accept this answer and ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Convert the data frame to a 3d array, apply `paste` over its first two dimensions giving matrix `m` and convert back to data frame:

```
a <- array(as.matrix(d), c(nrow(d), 3, ncol(d)/3))
m <- apply(a, 1:2, paste, collapse = "") 
as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

giving

```
  V1 V2 V3
1 ad be cf
2 gj hk il
```

**2)** Another approach if we have a grouping vector `g` is the following.  This does not require evenly spaced columns as we can define `g` arbitrarily.

```
g <- rep(1:3, length = ncol(d))
Paste0 <- function(x) do.call("mapply", c(paste0, x))
as.data.frame(lapply(split(as.list(d), g), Paste0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
   a  b  c
a ad be cf
g gj hk il
```

### Note

We used this 2x6 data frame as test input:

```
d <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "g"), V2 = c("b", "h"), V3 = c("c", 
  "i"), V4 = c("d", "j"), V5 = c("e", "k"), V6 = c("f", "l")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

which looks like this:

```
> d
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  a  b  c  d  e  f
2  g  h  i  j  k  l
```